# How to get a page ID from inside a header.php file

Tags: wordpress

How can I get the page ID from inside the header.php file?  $post->ID and get_the_ID() don't work.

Comment: What about this: `$ID = $wp_query->post->ID;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will work:

```
$ID = $wp_query->post->ID;
```